# Auto-incrementing user ID based on organisation ID

Tags: mysql

I have tables:

```
user(org_id, user_id, email, password)
organisation(org_id, org_name)
```

I want all users within an `organisation` to start with user ID 1 and increment by one each time another user is added. So I could have user 1, user 2, user 3 in one organisation, and user 1, user 2, user 3 within another `organisation`.

In a previous version of MySQL some years ago I did it like this:

```
create table users (
  org_id int unsigned, 
  user_id int unsigned auto_increment, 
  email varchar(100), 
  primary key (org_id, user_id), 
  unique key (email, org_id)
);

insert users (org_id, email) values(1, 'user1@example.com'), 
                                   (1, 'user2@example.com'), 
                                   (2, 'user3@example.com'), 
                                   (3, 'user4@example.com'), 
                                   (2, 'user5@example.com');
```

Which gave me the following table:

```
org_id | user_id | email

1 | 1 | user1@example.com

1 | 2 | user2@example.com

2 | 1 | user3@example.com

3 | 1 | user4@example.com

2 | 2 | user5@example.com
```

As you can see, users within each `org_id` start at `user_id` 1 and increment on each addition.

However now I can not create the table. When I run the query to create the table I get the error message "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Set a FK from users.org_id to organisation.org_id and make users.org_id AND users.user_id both PK with user_id = autonum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing your engine type to MyISAM from INNODB, you can make this work.

```
create table users (
 org_id int unsigned, user_id int unsigned auto_increment, 
 email varchar(100), 
 primary key (org_id, user_id), 
 unique key (email,  org_id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: You give up transaction processing by moving from InnoDB to MyISAM.

Comment: Yeah you're correct. To make work this behavior in innodb table, we need to write some stored procedure or function. If engine not a problem, then this will be fine.